# How do you launch from a pc (excel, cmd) an azure notebook?

Tags: python, excel, azure, launch

How do you launch from a pc (excel, cmd) an azure notebook?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workaround

If want to read it locally

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
print (df)
```

If you are trying to read from Azure Storage Account

```
ReadExcel=pd.read_excel('https://<account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file system>/<path>?<sas token>')
print(ReadExcel)
```

if you are trying to read from the instance

```
import pandas as pd  
from pandas import read_csv  
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv")  
print(data)
print("Dataset read successfully")
```

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Azure Jupyter Notebook](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-azure-ml-services-with-azure-notebook/)

Comment: thanks but by launch, i mean Execute / Trigger for example how can execute / trigger from my local PC a python .ipynb notebook saved in Azure ? thanks again!